# Problem of beginer with methods in other Class (Python)

Tags: python, database, sqlite, tkinter

I am trying to get data from JSON. Thereafter, I want to insert it into a new table. In my class DB I have 2 methods: `create_connect` and `add_records`. In `create_connect` method I had created variable 'cur' - cursor. Now, I want to use this variable in `add_records` method. How I can do that?

I tried the following code but it throws error:

```py
def create_connect(self, dbname):

    cur = con.cursor()

def add_records(self, id, date, open_p, close_p, high_p, low_p, dbname):

    cur.execute(sql_insert_query, recordTuple)
```

> NameError: name 'cur' is not defined

Answer (score 2):

use self.cur.

```
import sqlite3

class ClassName:

    def create_connect(self, dbname):

        con = sqlite3.connect(dbname)
        cur = con.cursor()
        return cur

    def add_records(self, id, date, open_p, close_p, high_p, low_p, dbname):
        cur = self.create_connect(dbname)
        cur.execute(sql_insert_query, recordTuple)
```